# Review indicator miscounting?

Tags: bug, reviews

It might be my misunderstanding, but...

I have an orange indicator suggesting I have (currently) 8 reviews to do, but my review queue is completely empty (all zeroes).

It's just me or is there something wrong?

Comment: To cite the linked duplicate: `This is because once you cross 10k rep -- the review counter in the statusbar changes to show the amount of reviews in-flight on the site as a whole. (I know, this seems to be one of the most confusing things that happens at 10k rep.)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many answers to this already, on every meta on S.E.  In a nutshell, the indicator doesn't count how many are available for you specifically; just how many are in the queue, period.  They say they can't make it smarter, even though it knows obviously when you go to that page.